# Is it possible to query day-partitioned BigQuery data over a range of dates without the wildcard _TABLE_SUFFIX method?

Tags: google-bigquery, google-analytics

I'm trying to query Google Analytics data in BigQuery (partitioned into discrete tables by day), but I cannot run it successfully in our dev environment due to the following restriction:

`"Invalid value: Wildcard table over a table protected by a customer-managed encryption key is not supported."`

This arises from the table suffix method of filtering to the desired date range over multiple tables, ex:

```
FROM [MyDataset]_*
WHERE _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN [dateStart] AND [dateEnd]
```

Is there an alternative way to query over a range of dates without the above method that doesn't require explicitly calling each of the required tables with UNION ALL?